# Plant found on lowland heath in south-east England

Tags: identification

I found this on a lowland heath (acid) in south east England. I'm pretty sure it's not native but it was in a very "natural" location. Can anyone identify it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meet **Nora Barlow** - a columbine hybrid ([*Aquilegia vulgaris var. stellata ‘Nora Barlow’*](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/131118/Aquilegia-vulgaris-var-stellata-Nora-Barlow-%28Barlow-Series%29-%28d%29/Details)) that must have escaped from some garden or park.

The likely reason that it seems so “comfortable is that columbine hybrids happily naturalize in areas where their wild relatives grow and Southern England is part of their native habitat.

Comment: Thanks Stephie. Great answer.